# Two different syntax for the GUI -> Different behaviours

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qt-designer

I'm looking into PyQt and something is definitely not clear to me.
Let's say I want to create a GUI with a button.
Lots of examples online have this form:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Example(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()


    def initUI(self):      

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 200, 140)
        self.setWindowTitle('Dialog')
        self.aaa = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.aaa.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 40, 113, 32))
        self.aaa.setObjectName("aaa")
        self.aaa.setText( "PushButton")
        self.show()



    def keyPressEvent(self, e):
        if e.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Return:
            self.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

However, if I create the same GUI with Designer and then I convert it to Python through 'pyuic5 -x test.ui -o test.py', I obtain a slightly different code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.setGeometry(300, 300, 200, 140)
        self.aaa = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.aaa.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 40, 113, 32))
        self.aaa.setObjectName("aaa")

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog"))
        self.aaa.setText(_translate("Dialog", "PushButton"))


    def keyPressEvent(self, e):
        if e.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Return:
            self.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_Dialog()
    ui.setupUi(Dialog)
    Dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Apart from the differences such as calling:

```
self.setGeometry(300, 300, 200, 140)
```

instead of

```
Dialog.setGeometry(300, 300, 200, 140)
```

There are some differences that I can't understand.

- keyPressEvent works in the first example, it doesn't work in the second
- if I press 'Escape' in the first example nothing happens, if I press it in the second the application closes immediately
- the button is highlighted in the second example (because it is setted as Default, and I found a way of disabling it) while it is not in the first case

I'm looking for guides and tutorial that explain this but I can only find examples with the first syntax, while the second one would be better for me as I can design the GUI with Designer and then export it in python for adding the events.
My practical questions are then:

- How can I avoid the escape button to quit my app in the second example?
- How can I have keyPressEvent working in the second example?

and more in general:

- Should I prefer the first or the second syntax, or are they equivalent?
- Is there a way of exporting a designer file '.ui' to a python file having the syntax as in the first example?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**How can I avoid the escape button to quit my app in the second example?**

This button is activated by default since in the second example you are using the `QDialog` widget that has this default behavior since they are used to create dialogs where the user must select an option, instead the first example is using a `QWidget` that is the most basic widget.

Solution: Use as template to Widget instead of some Dialog without Buttons, Dialog with Buttons Bottom or Dialog with Buttons Right.

**How can I have keyPressEvent working in the second example?**

Qt Designer creates a design class, does not create a widget, ie the class that creates fill a widget which is observed in the main of the first code, and only the widget has the event keyPressEvent. the solution is simple, you must create a class that inherits from Dialog and implement the filling of the widget with the class that Qt Designer provides.

```
class Dialog(QtWidgets.QDialog, Ui_Dialog):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QtWidgets.QDialog.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.setupUi(self)

    def keyPressEvent(self, e):
        if e.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Return:
            self.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Dialog()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Note:**

The following schema shows the templates that you use in Qt designer and the classes that you must inherit:

```
+-----------------------------+--------------+
| Template                    | Widget Class |
+-----------------------------+--------------+
| Dialog with Buttons Bottom  | QDialog      |  
| Dialog with Buttons Right   | QDialog      |
| Dialog without Buttons      | QDialog      |
| MainWindow                  | QMainWindow  |
| Widget                      | QWidget      | 
+-----------------------------+--------------+
```

In general you must use the following scheme:

```
class Some_Name(Widget_Class, Template):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Widget_Class.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.setupUi(self)
```

For more information check the following:

- http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html

Comment: Thank you, your explanation is extremely clear! I'll also go through the documentation you linked for having a better understanding of what's going on with the designer! Thanks again :D

Comment: @Fraccalo If my answer helps you do not forget to mark as correct, if you do not know how to do it check the following link: https://stackoverflow.com/tour